# Do you capitalize the names of holidays?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

I always thought the names of holidays were proper names, and should thus be capitalized "Christmas", "Thanksgiving", etc. However, I recently made a typo when talking about Christmas (Christmsa), and my spelling checker corrected it to be lower case "christmas". It knew what word I wanted, but made it lower case, where it would usually recognize incorrect capitalization.

So I wondered: Is my spelling checker wrong? Or is capitalization of holiday names not a requirement?

And either way, any insight on why the spelling checker would be this way?

Comment: Is your spell checker MS Word by chance?

Comment: Probably just a bug in the spellchecker.  FWIW, my version of MS Word properly corrects "chritmsas" to Christmas.

Comment: Because spellcheckers are dumb.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, capitalize the names of holidays:

> Christmas
>   Thanksgiving
>   Independence Day

... and so on.

Comment: Further, most terms containing "Christ" (as a reference to the head of the Christian church) are capitalized -- Christian, Christianity, Christ-like, Christendom, Christmas tree, etc.  It's actually a little jarring (for someone raised in US Christian culture) to be looking at, say, Norwegian Christmas materials and see lower-case terms use.